# jquery Autocomplete success JSON mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have issues with the jquery UI autocomplete plugin. I have no idea how to map the response that im getting back from the server.

Here's the JSON structure:

```
{
    categories: [
       {
          slug: "car-index",
          name: "Car",
          rank: "5"
       },
       {
          slug: "anim-index",
          name: "Animals",
          rank: "29"
       },
    ],
    queries: [
        "term1",
        "term2"
    ]
}
```

My autocomplete code :

```
$.ajax({
        url: autocompleteUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
                q: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
            response(
                $j.map( data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        name: item.categories.name,
                        slug: item.categories.slug,
                        rank: item.categories.rank,
                        query: item.queries
                    }
                 })
            );
```

**This code is giving errors. I can get it to work if I do the *map* on data.categories, but I need also the info from "Queries"** I have no idea how to return results from both places. Need to get all information (queries, name,slug,rank) in order to display the text in my render function too.

```
    }).data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $('<li></li>')
    .append('<a><span>' + item.name + '</span> - <span>Rank: ' + item.rank + '</span></a>')
    .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
    .appendTo(ul);

};
```

Im really stuck there, can someone help ?

Thanks

Comment: Do categories and queries have a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: The number of items in each is always different. There can be 2 categories and 15 queries, per exemple.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in the data returned in JSON format can be accessed using the `name.value` notation. For example, to access the property `categories`, which will return an array, we can simply call `data.categories`. To loop through the items in the array returned, we can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Also, I would recommend instead of relying on the `jqXHR.success`, you should chain a deferred object and use [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) after the AJAX call :)

```
$.ajax({
    url: autocompleteUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
            q: request.term
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    // Success function
    // Example of iterating through all elements in the array returned by data.categories
    $.each(data.categories, function() {
        $('<li />')
        .html('<a><span>' + this.name + '</span> - <span>Rank: ' + this.rank + '</span></a>')
        .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
        .appendTo('ul');
    });
});
```

You are a little vague with what you actually want to do with the returned data and how they should inserted into a DOM, but I have made a proof-of-concept fiddle to show you how to interate through both the `data.categories` and `data.queries` objects: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/15259aca/

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have to use _renderItem function in order to modify the autocomplete plugin dropdown. Meaning I have to map all the information I need in the success function.